# Feasibility of modifying BIND9 encryption

Tags: encryption, dns, bind

I am working on coming up for ideas on a final year project for my CS major. One of the ideas suggested by a lecturer that he would be interested in supervising would be an exploration of the application of [ID-based encyption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_encryption) to securing DNS. From my preliminary research, I am leaning towards a project whereby I attempt to marry DNSSEC with this encryption standard.

My idea was that I might be able to use the simple DNS levels of BIND9, minus DNSSEC, and build on top of them a customised DNSSEC-like scheme. I would presumably have to modify parts of the library too, in order to use the features of RFC 2535 such as the KEY and SIG RRsets with my new scheme. Or perhaps the best approach is to edit how DNNSEC is implemented in the library and attempt to rip out OpenSSL and replace it with hooks to my own mini-encryption library? Has anyone any experience on working with the BIND library that could tell me how bad of an approach this is, how the library lends itself to extensibility, etc.?

Comment: First, research the _current_ DNSSEC standard.  You need RFC4033+, not 2525.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify whether when you say "securing DNS" you mean:

1. cryptographically *signing* the *content* of an individual DNS message (at the transport level), or
2. cryptographically *encrypting* the *content* of an individual DNS message, or
3. cryptographically signing DNS zone *data*, so that it can't be spoofed

The three features are more or less completely orthogonal.

TSIG does the first - it prevents an individual packet from being modified while it's in transit, and only works from *hop to hop*.

DNScurve does the second, and therefore implicitly the first too (since if a packet is modified the decryption won't work), but isn't standardised.  It's an interesting idea, but it's a very long way from any significant deployment.

DNSSEC only does the last of the three.  It is intended to provide an *end to end* cryptographic proof that the data received by the DNS client is identical to that contained in the authoritative server, regardless of how many recursive resolvers were involved.

From the Wikipedia page ID-based encryption appears to be about securing *messages* between two parties, and not about signing *data*.  If that's correct, it's closer to TSIG or DNScurve than to DNSSEC.

Comment: The brief given to me was as follows: 

"The idea here is to do the same using IBE instead, so for example the IP address of the machine could be used to derive the public key of the machine that wishes to update its DNS record. If one can quickly and securely update the DNS record then this has implications for protocols like Mobile IP that require frequent routing updates due to the mobility of the nodes in the system."

From that and discussions, it's not really any of your three options. I'm in over my head here and am going to forget about the project. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at GSS-TSIG (RFC 3645) - this sounds closest to what you're looking for.  The normal problem with TSIG is that both ends must pre-agree a shared secret.  Having a more generic dynamic method would be A Good Thing(tm).